# is there something like AVPlayerViewController for playing audio on tvOS?

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv, avkit

In tvOS, is there an equivalent to the AVPlayerViewController for playing music with an cover and progress bar, like the one in the music app?

[AVPlayerViewController Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In tvjs player (https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlayer_Ref/) just set the type of the `mediaItem` (https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/MediaItem) to `audio`. Have a look at https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnectApp/tree/master/PlexConnectApp/js, comparing VideoPlayer.js and AudioPlayer.js.
I guess, using Swift/Foundation, things should be handled similar...

Comment: thanks, but I can't find a way to set the `AVPlayerViewController` to audio only using ObjC/Foundation..and i don't want to use TVJS..